# Apply equivalence rules to convert to CNF

Tags: propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I am having trouble seeing how I could apply the equivalence rules mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214338/how-to-convert-to-conjunctive-normal-form) to the following formula in order to convert it into Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF).

$$(p \wedge q) \vee (\neg p \wedge r)$$

I know the solution through [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20CNF%20%28%28a%20and%20b%29%20or%20%28not%28a%29%20and%20c%29%29), but I do not see how these rules could be applied in order to obtain the answer. These rules get a little confusing for me when a negation of a literal is involved. Could someone please help me to understand this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Converting_from_first-order_logic) we are given an algorithm to follow, and we will see that at each step all we need to do is step $5$.

$$(p \wedge q) \vee (\neg p \wedge r) \equiv ((p \wedge q) \vee \neg p) \wedge ((p \wedge q) \vee r) \quad \text{ distribute} \vee \text{ over } \wedge$$ 
$$\equiv ((p \vee \neg p)  \wedge (q \vee \neg p)) \wedge ((p \vee r) \wedge (q \vee r)) \quad \text{ again distribute} \vee \text{ over } \wedge $$ 
$(p \vee \neg p)$ is a tautology and we know that $t \wedge a \equiv a$ for any tautology $t$, so that we can just "throw out" $(p \vee \neg p)$.  This leaves us with:

$$(q \vee \neg p) \wedge ((p \vee r) \wedge (q \vee r)) \equiv (q \vee \neg p) \wedge (p \vee r) \wedge (q \vee r) \quad \text{ since } \wedge \text{ is associative} $$

This is in conjunctive normal form, although it is not exactly what Wolfram is giving.

Comment: You haven't written a conjunctive normal form or a disjunctive normal form.  The definition of such says they qualify as well-formed formulas or statement forms.  You haven't written a single wff.

Comment: I am also confused, it seems I have written the expression in conjunctive normal form per wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Converting_from_first-order_logic).  I don't see anything refering to uniqueness, so it seems like mine and Wolfram's answer could both be correct.  If I am mistaken, I will delete my answer... And also, what is your definition of wff? I don't why my formulas are not well-formed.  Again, I may be mistaken and not know the correct formulation rules.

Comment: A definition of a well-formed formula or statement form can go: 

1 All letters of the Latin alphabet qualify as well-formed formulas.
2 If **A** qualifies as a well-formed formula, then so does $\lnot$ **A**.
3 If **A**, as well as **B** qualify as well-formed formulas, then so does (**A**  $\land$ **B**).
4 If **A**, as well as **B** qualify as well-formed formulas, then so does (**A** $\lor$ **B**).
The logician Elliot Mendelson called well-formed formulas statement forms.  In his Schaum's Outline of Boolean Algebra on p. 12 he wrote...

Comment: "A statement form **A** is said to be in *disjunctive normal form* (dnf) if...  And we don't need the rest here.  I will remark that there do exist different definitions for well-formed formulas, and as I understand things you can use trees also.  However, what you have done here does NOT fall into either of those categories.  If you want to abbreviate well-formed formulas, please make it clear that you've abbreviated things somewhere.  I encourage you to at least consider indicating that restoration of parentheses or rewriting things can get done as it has in some texts.

Comment: Ok, I see that I did have the correct definition in mind, and I am aware (and I think most everyone who would actually care) that I am missing parenthesis.  But this is also very standard and although it may disqualify my formulas as well-formed I think most would abuse the notation in this way.  Although it would be good to explain that if I was writing a textbook, I don't think explaining this in my answer will do anything to clarify the problem the o.p. has.

Answer (score 0):

This formula is in Disjunctive normal form (DNF), so if you just use those rules to covert to CNF, it will cost much effort. But there is a trick to convert DNF to CNF quickly.

Let denote two new variables A, B such that:

- $A \to (p \wedge q) = \neg A \vee (p \wedge q) = (\neg A \vee p)\wedge(\neg A \vee q)$
- $B \to (\neg p \wedge r) = \neg B \vee(\neg p \wedge r)= (\neg B \vee \neg p)\wedge(\neg B \vee r)$

So your formula in CNF is $(A \vee B)$ together with the constraints above, which means:

$(A \vee B) \wedge (\neg A \vee p)\wedge(\neg A \vee q) \wedge (\neg B \vee \neg p)\wedge(\neg B \vee r)$

Comment: You haven't written a conjunctive normal form or a disjunctive normal form.  The definition of such says they qualify as well-formed formulas or statement forms.  You haven't written a single wff.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your comment. What I have written is not different from what given in here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form

Comment: See my comment to Ryan Sullivant's answer.  Also, the Wikipedia does NOT define what a logical formula consists of.  A well-formed formula does qualify as a logical formula.  You simply have not written any logical formulas.

Answer (score -1):

First write out the truth table:

```
 p   q   r  (p∧q)  (¬p∧r)  [(p∧q)∨(¬p∧r)]
 0   0   0    0        0           0
 0   0   1    0        1           1
 0   1   0    0        0           0
 0   1   1    0        1           1
 1   0   0    0        0           0
 1   0   1    0        0           0
 1   1   0    1        0           1
 1   1   1    1        0           1
```

Now how do you write a disjunctive normal form from this?  As a rough outline you interpret all "0s" as negations of the variables, and "1s" as the variables when and only when the statement evaluates to 1, and make an n-ary conjunction of that.  Then you make a disjunction of all that.  The conjunction normal form consists of the dual of the disjunctive normal form.  You can look at the rows where the statement form evaluates to 0 instead of to 1, and exchange "OR" for "AND".  We write a literal if it matches to 0, and the negation of the literal if it matches to 1 for the rows where we have a "0".

The definition of a conjunctive normal form says that they have to qualify as wffs or statement forms or significant expressions.  To spare your eyes and my labor of writing a string with many parentheses, I will hereafter use [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

Given an informal rule of detachment, we can thus define the relevant wffs as follows:

1. All lower case letters of the Latin alphabet qualify as wffs.
2. If $\alpha$ qualifies as a wff, then so does N$\alpha$.
3. If $\alpha$, $\beta$ qualify as wffs, then so does K$\alpha$$\beta$.
4. If $\alpha$, $\beta$ qualify as wffs, then so does A$\alpha$$\beta$.

Thus, Kpq represents the wff (in a distinct language) above the first column not falling underneath a variable.  KNpr represents the wff above the second column not falling underneath a variable, and AKpqKNpr represents the wff above the third column not falling underneath a variable.

AApqr only evaluates to 1 when one of it's variables takes on the value 1.  Otherwise it qualifies as false.  AApNqr only evaluates to 1 when Nq evaluates to 0, and so do p and r.  And so on, allowing us to infer

KKK AApqr AApNqr AANpqr AANpqNr as a conjunctive normal form.