# Find the conjunctive normal form in the smallest possible number of variables of $x+x^{'}y$.

Tags: boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form

> Find the conjunctive normal form in the smallest possible number of variables of $x+x^{'}y$.

$x+x^{'}y=(x+yy^{'})+x^{'}y$

How can I proceed?Please help.

The answer is given to be $x+y$ which I don't know how to get.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that to convert an expression into conjuctive normal form, we use a combination of five rules classified under:

- Double Negation
- De Morgan Laws
- Distributive Laws

Note that they are already outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214338/how-to-convert-to-conjunctive-normal-form/214352#214352).

---

Now, we can just use Rule 4 of the answer (Distributive law no.1) to get the required result as $$x \lor x' = \text { identity } $$

Comment: The answer is $x+y$

Comment: @New_User Yes, I know. Here, $\lor $ stands for $+$, $\land $ stands for $\cdot $. Just use Rule 4 and get the answer. $$x + x'y \equiv x \lor (x' \land y) $$

Answer (score 2):

$$x + x'y \overset{Distribution}{=} (x+x')(x+y) \overset{Complement}{=}1(x+y)\overset{Identity}{=}x+y$$